# Dynamic Array Error Help: '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function'

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been having trouble with the last bit of my code. I declared an instance of Grocery using the parameterized, copy and default constructor and made use of the operator= and operator<< overload. I am now having difficulty trying to create a dynamic array. I have to fill the array with the contents of my text filefileName.txt.

When I run this code I keep getting this one error:
Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion). Can I not access the setters in the array using >> (w/o overloading)? If not, how can I?

```
int main()
{
    // Parameter - Instance 1
    Grocery g1("NA", 0, "NA");
    g1.setName("Milk");
    g1.setQuant("1");
    g1.setUnit("Bottle");

    Grocery g2(g1); // Calls copy constructor

    // Default constructor - Instance 3
    //Grocery g3(); 

    // Operator =
    Grocery g4;
    cout << "Operator = Running" << endl;
    g4 = g2;
    cout << g4.getName() << endl;
    cout << g4.getQuant() << endl;
    cout << g4.getUnit() << endl << endl;


    // Operator <<
    cout << "Operator<< Running" << endl;
    Grocery g5("Salt", "1", "Bag");
    cout << g5 << endl;
    //cout << g5.getName();
    //cout << g5.getQuant();
    //cout << g5.getUnit();


    // Dynamic Array of Grocery
    Grocery* groceryArray;
    groceryArray = new Grocery[3];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("fileName.txt");


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> groceryArray[i].setName; // LINE ERROR IS HERE**
    }

    inputFile.close();
    delete[]groceryArray;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//Grocery.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Grocery
{
private:
    string* m_name;
    string* m_quant;
    string* m_unit;

public:
    Grocery(); // Default constructor
    Grocery(string n, string q, string u); // Parametered constructor
    ~Grocery(); // Destructor
    Grocery(const Grocery& rhs); // Copy constructor
    Grocery& operator=(const Grocery& rhs); // Operator=
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Grocery& rhs); //Operator>>
    string getName();
    void setName(string n);

    string getQuant();
    void setQuant(string q);

    string getUnit();
    void setUnit(string u);

};
```

```
#include "Grocery.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Grocery::Grocery() // Default constructor
{
    m_name = new string;
    m_quant = new string;
    m_unit = new string;

    *m_name = "N/A";
    *m_quant = "NA";
    *m_unit = "N/A";
}


Grocery::Grocery(string n, string q, string u) // Parameterized constructor
{
    //cout << "3 parameter constructor called" << endl;
    // Initializes member variables as parameter variables
    m_name = new string;
    m_quant = new string;
    m_unit = new string;

    *m_name = n;
    *m_quant = q;
    *m_unit = u;
}
Grocery::Grocery(const Grocery& rhs) // Copy
{
    m_name = new string;
    m_quant = new string;
    m_unit = new string;

    *m_name = *rhs.m_name;
    *m_quant = *rhs.m_quant;
    *m_unit = *rhs.m_unit;
}

Grocery& Grocery::operator=(const Grocery& rhs) // Operator=
{
    // Performs deep copy of other Grocery instance
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    *m_name = *rhs.m_name;
    *m_quant = *rhs.m_quant;
    *m_unit = *rhs.m_unit;
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Grocery& rhs) // Operator<<
{
    out << *rhs.m_name << endl << *rhs.m_quant << endl << *rhs.m_unit << endl;
    return out;
}


Grocery::~Grocery() // Destructor
{
    delete m_name;
    delete m_quant;
    delete m_unit;

    *m_name = nullptr;
    *m_quant = nullptr;
    *m_unit = nullptr;
}



string Grocery::getName() { return *m_name; }
void Grocery::setName(string n) { *m_name = n; }

string Grocery::getQuant() { return *m_quant; }
void Grocery::setQuant(string q) { *m_quant = q; }

string Grocery::getUnit() { return *m_unit; }
void Grocery::setUnit(string u) { *m_unit = u; }
```

Comment: What is `groceryArray[i].setName` really? How can you "input" to that? And you overload `operator<<` for output, why don't you overload `operator>>` for input?

Comment: Unrelated: You seem to come from a language where `new` is required to instantiate objects. In C++ it's _not_ and usually does more harm than good. You  can change your members to `string m_name;` and so on and save yourself much work. This way those strings will be automatically initialized and destroyed, no need for `new`.

Comment: Even more so: `*m_name = nullptr;` is outright wrong. It does not do what you think it to do. 1) Youre dereferencing a pointer you just deleted 2) You don't need to do anything and shouldn't do anything more as your object is being deleted right now (just deleting the pointer is enough) 3) It actually tries to assign `nullptr` to the `std::string` object pointed to by `m_name` which should explode in your face any minute now,

Comment: To set the pointer itself to `nullptr` use `m_name = nullptr` but as already stated above, that is not neccessary in this situation

Answer (score 2):

First things first: `groceryArray[i].setName` is a method of `Grocery` which makes the statement `**inputFile >> groceryArray[i].setName;` highly nonsensical.

What you want instead is to first read in a string and then change the name like so:

```
std::string name;
**inputFile >> name;
groceryArray[i].setName(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm still learning the ropes unfortunately. After making your change to the code I now get the error
 : '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)". This is similar to the last error except instead of "right-hand operand of type overloaded-function" it's now of type void

Comment: @Anonymous Probably because `**inputFile` is already wrong in your code and should be just `inputFile` instead. `**inputFile` double dereferences a pointer but `inputFile` is of type `std::ifstream` and not `std::ifstream**`

Comment: It's not that, I tried to bold the error line and didn't realize it wouldn't work, sorry my mistake. In the actual code it is just inputFile. Along with the previous error about type void, I'm also getting told that "no operator ">>" matches these operands on the inputFile >> groceryArray[i].setName(name) line

Comment: @Anonymous Use the code exactly as written above. I would strongly advice you to re-read about functions and function calls. `inputFile >> groceryArray[i].setName(name)` is not what i wrote and is something different entirely.